# Anonymous variable objects vs real objects for r-value

Tags: c++, object, constructor, anonymous

In C++, all of these ways of declaring variables with initial values work (given some type `T` that can be initialized with `7`):

```
T a = T(7);

T b(7);

T c(7);
T d = c;
```

But this does not:

```
// error: expected primary-expression before 'cd'
T f = T e(7);
```

Why isn't this last allowed?  (I expected it to declare both 'e' and 'f'.)

Comment: I don't see the purpose of allowing declarations there instead of just having two lines.

Answer (score 0):

The initialiser has to be an expression. `Derived cd(7)` is a declaration, not an expression. `Derived(7)` is an expression, so can be used there.

If you want to declare two variables in one declaration statement, then the syntax is

```
Derived cd(7), cc = cd;
```

with a separate declarator for each.